# Apply borders till last row and last column of dataframe

Tags: python, excel, border

I am trying to apply borders to the dataframe, when i am using below code it is applying to all cells beyond my data range. I want to apply borders till last row of dataframe. Kindly help. please find the below code that i am using.

```
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
format = workbook.add_format()
format.set_align('center')
format.set_align('vcenter')
format.set_border()

worksheet.set_column('A:E',10, format)
```

I want the borders to be applied till last row of dataframe.

Comment: sorry.. it is not working

Comment: my bad, its `openpyxl` api not `pandas`.